# I want 0 will not be displayed, keeps display 0 before FULL

Tags: javascript

I have a simple program with javascript and localStorage. There is a variable slot that is equal to 10. When i click "Deduct" it decrements. But the problem is it displays 0 (zero) before the document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL"; will trigger. I don't know why. What I want is when the slot reaches 0, it does not display zero already and it displays FULL.

Javascript:

```
    window.onload = function(){
    slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");

    if (slot == null) {
        slot = 10;
    }

    document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        reduceSlot();
    })
}

function reduceSlot() {
    if (slot >= 1) {
        slot--;
        document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;
        localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
        document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="slot">10</p>
<a href="javascript:reduceSlot(1)" id="button1">Deduct</a>
<button onclick="window.localStorage.clear();">Clear All</button>
```

Here's the link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/K8stQ/

Comment: Haha, I have read `before NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want, but if you want the **last** element to be `1`, then this is the solution:

Instead of

```
if (slot >= 1) {
```

Use

```
if (slot > 1) { //simply "greater", instead of "greater or equal"
```

Why is this needed? Let's clear up this block:

```
if (slot >= 1) { //checks if slot is greater than, or equal to 1. 
    slot--;     // **in this case**, equivalent to slot = slot-1;
    document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot; //set the value of slot to element
    localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
}
else {
    document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
}
```

Now let's see what goes wrong.

- method called
- slot is **2**

  - if condition evaluates to **true**, that branch is executed
  - slot is decremented, slot is now **1**
  - the value of slot(**1**) is set to the element
  - method ended
- method called again
- slot is **1**

  - if condition evaluates to **true**, that branch is executed
  - slot is decremented, slot is now **0** -- OOPS, this is what we did not want
  - the value of slot(**0**) is set to the element
  - method ended
- method called again
- slot is **0**

  - if condition evaluates to **false**, the else branch is executed
  - the value **FULL** is set to the element
  - method ended

So what is there to be done: stop 1 step earlier: don't allow to slot reach 1...

Comment: Yeah this is the problem he seems to be facing - he wants FULL to be displayed instead of 0.

Comment: WOW. An answer with great and understandable explanation. I appreciate your help. I'm still new and learning thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you decrement it to 0, you don't change the display until the next time you click. You need to make that decision right after decrementing, when you're updating the innerText:

```
function reduceSlot() {
    if (slot >= 1) {
        slot--;
        localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
        if (slot > 0) {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = slot;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/K8stQ/3/)